# Disable shipping method when a cart item has a specific shipping class?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I try to disable a shipping method if a specific shipping class is in the cart. I'm using the newest woocommerce version.

Below is my Code for my task.
It's placed at the end of my `functions.php` file of my Theme.

Sadly its not working.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
    $shipping_class_target = 513;           // ID OF MY SHIPPING_CLASS
    $in_cart = false;
    foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        if( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
            $in_cart = true;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if( $in_cart ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:2'] );     //VALUE:ID OF MY SHIPPING METHOD
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested simplifying a little your code (with the ids of my WC settings) **and it works**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function custom_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item  ) {
        $product = $cart_item[ 'data' ]; // The WC_Product object
        $shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id();

        if( isset($rates['flat_rate:2']) && $shipping_class_id == 513 ) { // <== ID OF MY SHIPPING_CLASS
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:2'] ); // Removing specific shipping method
            break; // we stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

**So your code should work too** *(if you have set the correct IDs)*

> **BUT** you need *(after saving your code to the function.php file of your active theme)*:
>
> 1. **To remove all cart items** that are remaining in cart when testing.
> 2. **To refresh the shipping caches:** 
>    To do it, you can go in a shipping zone and disable one "flat rate" *(for example)* and "save". Then re-enable that "flat rate" and "save". You are done.

**Now you can test again and it should work**

Comment: You are awesome! The Cache refresh did it for me! Ty Sir.

Comment: Little late to the party, just quick question `var_dump($rates)` outputs nothing on the `/cart` page. New to wordpress here.

Comment: @SanjokGurung As this is a filter, to have an idea of the data from shipping rates you should better try anywhere else:  `echo '<pre>'; print_r(WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')); echo '</pre>';`