# Disable specific shipping method just for a cart item uses a specific shipping class ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

From *[Disable specific shipping method if a cart item uses a specific shipping class ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598944/disable-specific-shipping-method-if-a-cart-item-uses-a-specific-shipping-class-i/45600937#45600937)* answer code, how if there is another item in cart which does not have that shipping class ID and want to show `flat_rate:2` again according to product shipping class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function custom_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    $found = $others = false; // Initializing
    $shipping_class_id  = 513; // <== ID OF YOUR SHIPPING_CLASS
    $shipping_rate_id   = 'flat_rate:2'; // <== Targeted shipping rate ID

    // Checking cart items for current package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data']; // The WC_Product Object
        
        if( $product->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_id ) { 
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $others = true;
        }
    }
    
    if( $found && ! $others && isset($rates[$shipping_rate_id]) ) {
        unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id]); // Removing specific shipping method
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:**
>
> 1. This code is already saved on your functions.php file.
> 2. In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save. 
>    **You are done** and you can test it.

Comment: Thank you alot Loic :)